# FullCalendar - when prev / next buttons are clicked, left/right chevrons are increased by one after every click..?

Tags: php, html, jquery, fullcalendar

Please help!!

I have fullcalendar loaded in my local admin dashboard template.

Whenever I click the next / prev navigation buttons the chevrons in those buttons increase by one as pictures below.

My FullCalendar code is as follows.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
    var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
    initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
    headerToolbar:{
        left:   'today',
        center: 'title',
        right:  'prev,next'
    },
    buttonText: {
        today:  'Today',
        month:  'Month',
        week:   'Week',
        day:    'Day',
        list:   'List'
    },
    themeSystem: 'bootstrap',
    height: 500,
    editable:true,
    events: 'system/events.php',
    selectable:true,
    selectHelper:true
    });
calendar.render();
});
```

I've tried uninstalling and re-installing fullcalendar, using local installation and also CDN.
Neither of which solve the problem.

I'm sure it must be something simple however I'm not that

As i can't embed images i've shared via OneDrive: [Images Here](https://adcitsolutions-my.sharepoint.com/:f:/g/personal/tony_ukwebservices_co_uk/EmoMSfRA-ntBp7jcK7v7n2oBhOXt68PcCQv0S5_J4FuJVQ?e=tuEdGd)

Comment: please show your html code (and css) to have a sample functional..

Comment: Try it without the theme loaded and see if you have the same problem or not.

Comment: Also please state exactly what version of fullCalendar and exactly what version of bootstrap you are using.

Comment: @ADyson thank you for your help, I removed themeSystem: "bootstrap" and the issue did not happen so i've re-checked the bootstrap setup for fullcalendar and stripped it back. After piecing the header section back together bit by bit it's now working as it should.... thanks again!!

Answer (score 0):

The solution.....

@ADyson thank you for your help, I removed themeSystem: "bootstrap" as recommended and the issue did not occur.

So i've re-checked the bootstrap setup for fullcalendar and stripped it back.

After piecing the header section back together bit by bit it's now working as it should....

I can't honestly say what the issue was specifically however going back over the header section did the trick..

Many thanks @ADyson